# Is there a Common Sharing UI in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I know how to use the various [tasks/launchers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff769550(v=vs.105).aspx) in Windows Phone to share a link or status on twitter, etc. However, is there anything built into the Windows Phone 8.x API to create a sharing screen like the one shown in the image below?

I've seen this same screen in both native Windows Phone apps (e.g. when tap-n-hold to share an app in the app list) as well as 3rd party apps (e.g. IMDB). Seeing this, I'd like to think this is available to be used by custom apps

Can anyone tell me if this exists as a shared component/API? If not, does anyone have some sample code for creating the page dynamically?

[image: Sharing Page in Windows Phone]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it turns out there is an API (via the Share Contract) in Windows Phone for this. It is called DataTransferManager.ShowShareUI and you can find out more [information about it here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.datatransfermanager.showshareui.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is not others shared component/API (I also try to find it).

But by using Launchers you help provide a consistent user experience throughout the Windows Phone platform, so users already know "how to share".

Comment: I was suspecting that might be the case. However, I've seen this exact screen used in a lot of 3rd party (i.e. non-Microsoft) apps so I'd really like to find some sample code that shows how to create the list dynamically (e.g. How was Tweetium detected and the app icon displayed for it?).